# Turn Off ServiceStack Logging

Tags: c#, log4net, servicestack

ServiceStack's internal logging isn't something I want to have in my logs. How do we disable the internal logging, or at least suppress it so it doesn't clog the log?

Comment: This seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868410/servicestack-how-to-disable-default-exception-logging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When configuring your LogManager just set it to an instance of NullLogFactory

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new NullLogFactory();
```

Comment: I still want to be able to log, I just don't want ServiceStack's internal logging to clog up my actual logging. I'd like to disable ServiceStack's internal logging (without recompiling ServiceStack).

Comment: In that case you can set EndpointHostConfig.DebugMode = false

Comment: Setting DebugMode to false didn't work for me - still getting internal ServiceStack errors. Example: ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.NotFoundHttpHandler

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack Ver 5 >

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
            DefaultRedirectPath = "/metadata",
            DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json,
            AppendUtf8CharsetOnContentTypes = new HashSet<string> { MimeTypes.Html, MimeTypes.Json },
            DebugMode = false,
            LogFactory = new NullLogFactory(),
            EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(disableFeatures)
)
```