# ServiceStack - how to disable default exception logging

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, servicestack

In line with [the ServiceStack documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling), we have a global service exception handler. The docs say that this handler should log the exception then call `DtoUtils.HandleException`, like this:

```
private object LogServiceException(object request, Exception exception)
{
    var message = string.Format("Here we make a custom message...");
    _logger.Error(message, exception);
    return DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, exception);
 }
```

This results in the error being logged twice, since [`DTOUtils.HandleException` also logs it](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServiceHost/DtoUtils.cs), in a less customised format. Yes, I much prefer this to the DTOUtils logging and don't want to just use that.

How do we turn off `DTOUtils` logging while retaining the rest of the functionality? Nobody likes getting twice as many error emails as they should.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you require the logging in your exception handler? If not why not simply remove it from there and let DtoUtils log the exception?

Comment: If  you create the  ServiceRunner, as you can read in the same documentation,   the error is logged twice ?  [Fine grain error handling using the New API's ServiceRunner](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling)

Comment: Yes, it is logged twice with a ServiceRunner. Docs on ServiceRunner are quite sparse, but it looks like if you make your own ServiceRunner you can logthe url from IRequestContext, and then you call "return base.HandleException(requestContext, request, ex);" .. which calls  DtoUtils.HandleException which does 2 things - make the error response and logs the exception. I wish it was more Single-responsibility.

Comment: I have not time to test it. But in my code  I don't return the base.HandleException  or I return it, under condition. I  create a response  using DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse ... In this case, it is logged twice, once, or not at all ?

Comment: Yes, CreateErrorResponse looks like the way to go and I am testing it out. Can you update the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following code solves your problem.

based  on the documentation  [New API, Custom Hooks, ServiceRunner](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api#custom-hooks)

and [Fine grain error handling using the New API's ServiceRunner](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#fine-grain-error-handling-using-the-new-apis-servicerunner)

in AppHost.Configure

```
   LogManager.LogFactory = new ServiceStack.Logging.Support.Logging.ConsoleLogFactory();
```

then in AppHost class

```
         public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(ActionContext      actionContext)
          {
               return new MyServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext);
            }
```

in the ServiceRunner class

```
       public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T>
       {

            public override object HandleException(IRequestContext requestContext, T request, Exception ex)
              {
                  if ( isYourCondition ) 
                  {
                        ResponseStatus rs = new ResponseStatus("error1", "your_message");
                        // optionally you can add custom response errors
                             rs.Errors = new List<ResponseError>();
                             rs.Errors.Add(new ResponseError());
                             rs.Errors[0].ErrorCode = "more details 2";

                            // create an ErrorResponse with the ResponseStatus as parameter
                            var errorResponse = DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, ex, rs);
                             // log the error
                             Log.Error("your_message", ex);
                             return errorResponse;

                   }
                   else
                        return base.HandleException(requestContext, request, ex);
               }

            }
```

if you return the base.HandleException, it calls internally the DtoUtils.HandleException. 
You will see in console, one log error only.

In client, if you handle the WebServiceException for custom errors.

```
            catch (WebServiceException err)
            {
                if ( err.ResponseStatus.Errors != null)
               { // do something with err.ResponseStatus.Errors[0].ErrorCode; 
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `DtoUtils.HandleException` as it logs the error. Don't call `ServiceRunner.HandleException` either, it calls `DtoUtils.HandleException`.

Call `DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse` to make the response (it is used by `DtoUtils.HandleException`). The `ToResponseStatus` helper is also in `DtoUtils`

My AppServiceRunner is now like this:

```
public class AppServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T>
{
    public AppServiceRunner(AppHost appHost, ActionContext actionContext)
        : base(appHost, actionContext)
    {
    }

    public override object HandleException(IRequestContext requestContext,
        T request, Exception ex)
    {   
        LogException(requestContext, request, ex);

        var responseStatus = ex.ToResponseStatus();
        return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, ex, responseStatus);
    }

    private void LogException(IRequestContext requestContext, T request, Exception ex)
    {
        // since AppHost.CreateServiceRunner can be called before AppHost.Configure
        // don't get the logger in the constructor, only make it when it is needed
        var logger = MakeLogger();
        var requestType = typeof(T);
        var message = string.Format("Exception at URI:'{0}' on service {1} : {2}",
            requestContext.AbsoluteUri, requestType.Name, request.ToJson());

        logger.Error(message, ex);
    }

    private static ILog MakeLogger()
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AppServiceRunner<T>));
    }
}
```

Now the only service errors that I get are those generated by this code.

Comment: Why do you think that my answer never call DtoUtils.HandleException directly; or indirectly  ?  Did you read my answer ?   I  don't understand you.

Comment: your question was  about the  "the error being logged twice...nobody likes getting twice as many error".

Comment: This did not work for me. ServiceStack still writes to the log on its own.

Comment: Actually it did work, but I had an error in a call to another service, and ServiceClientBase always writes errors regardless of any configuration.