# Do I have access to the request dto when I'm handling exceptions occuring outside of services?

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

With ServiceStack, it's important to implement exception handling/logging in two places:

1. [Inside of each](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18903322/109941) `ServiceRunner<T>`.

   ```
      public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T>
      {    
           public override object HandleException(IRequestContext requestContext, T request, Exception ex)
             {
                   // Implement your exception handling/logging here.
                   // T request is your request DTO.
             }
       }
   ```
2. [Inside of AppHost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32405346/109941), so that you can handle unhandled exceptions occuring outside of services.

   ```
   public override void Configure(Container container)
   {
       ExceptionHandler = (req, res, operationName, ex) =>
       {
           //Handle Unhandled Exceptions occurring outside of Services
           //E.g. Exceptions during Request binding or in filters:
       }
    }
   ```

My Question:

- In #1, you have easy access to the request DTO (i.e. for logging purposes).
- Do I have access to the request DTO (or the request payload equivalent) when I'm handling exceptions occuring outside of services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ServiceStack v4 the Request DTO is available from `IRequest.Dto`, but you would instead register your Service and Unknown Exception handlers with `IAppHost.ServiceExceptionHandlers` and `IAppHost.UncaughtExceptionHandlers`

In ServiceStack V3, you could register a GlobalRequestFilter that stores the Request DTO in `IRequestContext.Items` dictionary which you can get later from the Request Context.