# Can built-in logging messages be turned off?

Tags: servicestack

Once logging is configured with

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(configureLog4Net: true);
```

it can be used anywhere with

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("foo);
log.Error("foo");
```

I get it. The problem is that Service Stack uses the same logger for various built-in internal messages. For example, if request is submitted for a non-existing route, Service Stack logs "ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.NotFoundHttpHandler - ::1 Request not found:".

Is there a way to disable or turn off those internal messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn Off ServiceStack Logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598391/turn-off-servicestack-logging)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598391/turn-off-servicestack-logging turns off both SS internal and application logging. I still want my application to log, but suppress internal logging. I am checking @mythz solution.

Comment: Did you read the comments for the accepted answer?  It addressed that exact concern: `EndpointHostConfig.DebugMode = false`.

Comment: Yes, I tried "DebugMode = false" - didn't work. In NotFoundHttpHttpHandler (SS internal class) the log is created by  private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(NotFoundHttpHandler)); and then it simply used by  Log.ErrorFormat("{0} Request not found: {1}", request.UserHostAddress, request.RawUrl); I don't see how flipping DebugMode would help in this situation. Note this isn't just that handler, there are many others like ServiceStack.Redis, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up.  The comment about setting `DebugMode = false` had an upvote so I was hoping it was a possible solution.  You might want to consider adding a comment to the question I linked to indicating that setting the debug mode off doesn't disable logging.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Log4Net you should be able to [filter Log messages by type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5504173/85785), otherwise some of ServiceStack's internal logging can be controlled in your AppHost by overriding:

```
public override void OnLogError(Type type, string message, Exception innerEx=null)
{
    if (!SuppressLogs(type))
        base.OnLogError(type, message, innerEx);
}
```

I've also just changed `NotFoundHttpHandler` to route messages to route error messages to `OnLogError()` from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f236e43473769c9b94e1038d26523b129741f7c0) so you'll be able to suppress messages by overriding the above method.

This change is available from v4.0.61 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Log4Net filter worked, thank you! Question on OnLogError - will it take care of ServiceStack.Redis.*, ServiceStack.OrmLite.*, ServiceStack.Dto*, and ServiceStack.Messaging* events as well? We have a ton of those.

Comment: Yeah it should do, they follow the same logging patern